# Rack 'method not found'

Tags: ruby, rack

I can't seem to see what's up with this piece of code:

```
class Cherry
    class << self
        def call env
            self::Application.call
        end
    end
end

class Cherry
    class Application
        def call env
            #Framework logic
        end
    end
end

run Cherry
```

That's the part of my application that is not working. I have no idea why: 
`NoMethodError at / undefined method 'call' for Cherry::Application:Class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust a couple of things.

When you are defining the `call` method inside of `Application`, you are defining it as an instance method, then you are attempting to call it as a class method, so lets fix the definition to be a class method definition:

```
class Cherry
    class Application
        def self.call env
            #Framework logic
        end
    end
end
```

Next there will be a new error, about not passing the right number of arguments to the `call` method, so we add the `env` param to where you are calling the `call` method.

```
class Cherry
    class << self
        def call env
            self::Application.call env
        end
    end
end
```

Hope that helps!